Вылезает ошибка Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: BUTTON_DATA_INVALID на telebot, python
Нужна помощь срочно!
У меня выходит такая ошибка:
2024-06-16 10:31:27,472 (__init__.py:1221 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: BUTTON_DATA_INVALID"
2024-06-16 10:31:27,473 (__init__.py:1223 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1215, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 150, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/main.py", line 237, in chooseTopicPost
    featurePoint([str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id)), str(max(rdb.timeData.getFor_real_id(message.chat.id)["ids"]))], topic, dataPost, 0)
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/main.py", line 270, in featurePoint
    bot.send_message(
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1755, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 273, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 168, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
  File "/home/runner/IaandmalODIoZhKA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 195, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: BUTTON_DATA_INVALID
"

полный код на replit
часть кода:
if step==1:
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id-1)
    dataPost["Description"] = str(message.text)
    db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))]["ids"].append(max(db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))]["ids"])+1)
    db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))][str(max(db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))]["ids"]))]={"message":message}
    featurePoint([str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id)), str(max(rdb.timeData.getFor_real_id(message.chat.id)["ids"]))], topic, dataPost, 0)

def touchData(Data, message, topic, dataPost):
  print("touchData", '=', Data)
  #return ">:("
  db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))]["ids"].append(max(db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))]["ids"])+1)
  db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))][str(max(db["timeData"][str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id))]["ids"]))]={"message":message}
  
  r = '{"message":'+str([str(rdb.users.get_id(message.chat.id)), str(max(rdb.timeData.getFor_real_id(message.chat.id)["ids"]))])+', "topic":'+str(topic)+',  "dataPost":'+str(dataPost)+', "data":'+str(Data)+'}'
  return r

def featurePoint(message, topic, dataPost, point=0):
  message = rdb.timeData.getFor_id(message[0])[message[1]]["message"]
  if topic == 1:
    if point==0:
      genderKey = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
      d = {
        "message":message,
        "topic":topic,
        "dataPost":dataPost
      }
      print(
        touchData("boy", message, topic, dataPost),
        "=",
        type(touchData("boy", message, topic, dataPost)))
      genderKey.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("Мальчик",
          callback_data=base64.b64encode(zlib.compress((touchData("boy", message, topic, dataPost)).encode("utf-8"))).decode('utf-8')
        ),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Девочка",
          callback_data=base64.b64encode(zlib.compress((touchData("girl", message, topic, dataPost)).encode("utf-8"))).decode('utf-8')
        )
      )
      bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "Одежда для девочки или мальчика? :",
        reply_markup=genderKey
      )


Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.
